# What are some LEGO Christmas trees designs I can build?

Tags: building, design

It's Christmas time, and I'd like to build a Christmas tree to add to my winter scenes. Unfortunately the large LEGO pine tree is a little small, and also doesn't offer much by way of decorating opportunity.

[image]

What are some larger (but not too large!) and nicer-looking Christmas tree designs I can build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the design I created last year for the [Winter Bash 2018 Building Competition](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/451/winter-bash-2018-building-competition).

[image: Finished and Decorated Model]

It's very detailed and has many outward-facing studs to which decorations can be attached.

Here's some instructions for building the tree without decorations (note that many of the pieces are internal and do not have to be green).

[image: Instructions]

(Click the image to view the instructions larger)

NOTE: In step 9, you will need to rotate some of the stems to avoid overlapping in order to attach them all.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a brick-built design I've been using for a few years. It doesn't have many decoration points, but it is fairly small and simple to build.

[image: Final build]

Here's some instructions for building the tree.

[image: Instructions]

As a final step, you can add a 1x1 cylinder for the tree trunk to the bottom.